# Magento customer account links in phtml file

Tags: magento, url, php

Hi I am trying to implement three links in a phtml file. At this place I have no block, where I can set these link, that´s why I cannot use a xml file. These links are:

```
/customer/account/edit/

/customer/address/

/sales/order/history/
```

Is there a way to get the url of these pages without setting them hard in a href?

Thank´s in advance

Daniel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't much performance difference, but an alternative can be found below;

```
<a href="<?php echo Mage::getUrl('customer/account/edit'); ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Edit'); ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Edit'); ?></a>
<a href="<?php echo Mage::getUrl('customer/address'); ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Address'); ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Address'); ?></a>
<a href="<?php echo Mage::getUrl('sales/order/history'); ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('History'); ?>"><?php echo $this->__('History'); ?></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
 <a href="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl() ?>customer/account/edit">Edit</a>
 <a href="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl() ?>customer/address">Address</a>
 <a href="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl() ?>sales/order/history">History</a>
```